# AWK, add text before each column strange behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to add before each column a different text and i'm using this command:

```
top -b -n1  | tail -n +8 | grep -v top | head -6 | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } $1 = "pid=" $1, $2 = "user=" $2' | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

This works, but if I add another column:

```
top -b -n1  | tail -n +8 | grep -v top | head -6 | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } $1 = "pid=" $1, $2 = "user=" $2, $9 = "cpu=" $9' | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

I get an error:

```
awk: linea com.:1: BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } $1 = "pid=" $1, $2 = "user=" $2, $9 = "%cpu=" $9 awk: linea com.:1:                                 ^ syntax error
```

The syntax error is on "," after "$2".

I don't understand why. The full output of command (without prepend a text before each column) is for example:

```
2015-05-31 11:16:08 1589 root 12,4 2,2 Xorg

2015-05-31 11:16:08 3 root 6,2 0,0 ksoftirqd/0

2015-05-31 11:16:08 1 root 0,0 0,1 init

2015-05-31 11:16:08 2 root 0,0 0,0 kthreadd

2015-05-31 11:16:08 5 root 0,0 0,0 kworker/0:0H

2015-05-31 11:16:08 7 root 0,0 0,0 rcu_sched
```

And I need a result like this:

```
2015-05-31 11:16:08 1589 root 12,4 2,2 Xorg

2015-05-31 11:16:08 pid=3 user=root %cpu=6,2 %mem=0,0 command=ksoftirqd/0

2015-05-31 11:16:08 pid=1 user=root %cpu=0,0 %mem=0,1 command=init

2015-05-31 11:16:08 pid=2 user=root %cpu=0,0 %mem=0,0 command=kthreadd

2015-05-31 11:16:08 pid=5 user=root %cpu=0,0 %mem=0,0 command=kworker/0:0H

2015-05-31 11:16:08 pid=7 user=root %cpu=0,0 %mem=0,0 command=rcu_sched
```

Until column user it works. Can someone help me please?
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The syntax error is on "," after "$2". I don't understand why.

Because multiple commands which appear on the same line need to get separated by a `;` and not a `,`. (Looking at the manual would help)

However, you are currently using a lot of tools for tasks that can be simply done with `awk`. You can use a single `awk` command for that:

```
top -b -n1 |\
  awk 'NR>7&&!/top/&&c++<6{$1= "pid=" $1;$2= "user=" $2;print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0}' OFS='\t'
```

Explained better as a muli-line script:

```
    NR>7           # Skip the first 7 lines     
&&  !/top/         # Skip lines containing the term 'top'
&&  c++<6   {      # Limit output to 6 lines

    $1= "pid=" $1  # Fix pid field
    $2= "user=" $2 # Fix user fields

    # Print the modified line with a timestamp in front of it
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this way i output all columns, i need print only some columns. I will play with it to find out

Comment: @maurelio79 Which columns do you want to output?

Comment: Then simply print those columns instead of `$0`. Like this: `awk 'NR>7&&!/top/&&c++<6{$1= "pid=" $1;$2= "user=" $2;print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),$1,$2,$9,$10,$12}' OFS='\t'`

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest to follow some `awk` tutorials and read the manual. You'll see it is quite simple but super-powerful..

Answer (score 1):

In the [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pattern-Overview.html#Pattern-Overview) section `from, till` denotes a [range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html).

That's way it "worked" (= was syntactically correct and didn't cause an error) for two values.

The commands you want to execute on the matched lines are called [actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Action-Overview.html#Action-Overview), and you should put them within curly braces: `{ ... }`.

```
{ $1 = "pid=" $1; $2 = "user=" $2; $9 = "cpu=" $9; print }
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. If i write:
`top -b -n1  | tail -n +8 | grep -v top | head -6 | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $1 = "pid=" $1} { $2 = "user=" $2 } { $9 = "cpu=" $9 }' | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }`

I don't get any output

Comment: Sorry, I thought you're familiar with awk. Updated the answer.

Comment: Don't be sorry and thanks, bur still i get no output:
`top -b -n1  | tail -n +8 | grep -v top | head -6 | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $1 = "pid=" $1; $2 = "user=" $2; $9 = "cpu=" $9 }' | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'`

Ok now it works!! Thanks very much!!

Comment: @maurelio79 The pipe is looking horrible! Note that you can do all of that with just a single `awk` command.